# Simple trim of a date-time

Tags: date, join, trim

I have two tables I want to be able to join. One has dates in the format "2019-11-20", and there are instances on a daily basis. The other table contains weekly runs of a model in the format "2020-02-01 15:16:17.192837" How do i join these tables so that the daily occurrences are linked up with the weekly model runs?

Comment: If they are truly strings (please say they aren't) you could just append a midnight time `00:00:00.000000` and perform the join

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are of type date and datetime, you can "cast" the datetime on the ON clause as in `ON SimpleDate = Cast(ADateTime as date)`